# Keep in-app purchases across two apps?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

consider two apps:

- Free Version with in-app purchases
- Premium Version with in-app purchases

In-app purchases are certain items.

The premium version is able to do different things with those items.

I would like to sell the premium version, but keep the in-app purchases the user might have purchased within the free version-assuming the the user uses the same itunes account.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance, marimba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know is to upload the customer's product list to a server, then give both programs access to the server. That doesn't solve the problem of having to create two sets of In-App Purchases in iTunes Connect.

BTW this is just ONE way that Apple's IAP is not up to the task.